# Laravel 5 - LAMP (Cannot display any page other then welcome)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have installed Laravel 5 and got to display the welcome page. But haven't been able to display any other page. I have installed with following settings:

In **/etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.example.com.conf**

```
DocumentRoot   /var/www/laravel/public
```

In **/var/www/laravel/app/Http/routes.php**

```
// ---- THIS DOESN'T WORK
Route::get('/simple', function () {
    return View::make('simple');
});

// ---- THIS WORK FINE
Route::get('/', function () {
    return View::make('welcome');
});
```

In **/var/www/laravel/public**

```
$ ls -> index.php   robots.txt   web.config
```

In **/var/www/laravel/resources**

```
$ ls -> errors   vendor   simple.blade.php   welcome.blade.php
// welcome.blade.php -> gets displayed
// simple.blade.php -> doesn't get displayed
```

Comment: are you getting any error message ? enable debug and post your error message.

Comment: no error messages. Just 404 Page Not Found

Comment: In simple.blade.php, I have copied the exact code of welcome.blade.php

Comment: Check  / with "welcome" template first. Then /simple with welcome template.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried php artisan command from command prompt.

php artisan route:cache

We have to run this command after adding new route.

Comment: do I need to specify complete path of route.php and alter command like:    **php artisan /app/Http/route:cache**

Comment: no, just run the command after going inside your laravel project.
if your project path is /var/www/html/laravel-project, Then go to /var/www/html/laravel-project in command prompt and run the command.

Comment: Didn't worked it shows:                                                                      Route cache cleared!
                                                           
  [LogicException]                                                   
  Unable to prepare route [simple] for serialization. Uses Closure.

Answer (score 0):

The mod_rewrite enabled?

The .htaccess file good?

Answer (score 0):

sudo a2enmod rewrite
In your apache configuration file(apache2.conf) change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

Then restart apache using::
sudo service apache2 restart

// change the group of project/app/storage to www-data and change folder permission too
$ sudo chmod -R gu+w app/storage

Answer (score -1):

/simple route may be missing. Check it with "welcome" template first. Chmod 777 to cache as well. Hope, it is not related to case sensitive file names.

Comment: `chmod 777` -> nonononono! Never ever run `chmod 777`. It is practically never required! Not even for "testing purposes". If the file is readable, then it's readable. If it's writable by the `user` or `group` that need to write to it, then it's writable. There is absolutely zero need to give everyone write permissions, and forgetting to `chmod` it back to something sane is exactly how multinationals get hacked. Just don't do it. Ever. I wrote [an introduction of Unix permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/660921). Please read it!